# a little problem about use of lagrange theorem

Tags: calculus

[image]

As the picture depicted,I wonder what the problem lies on?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: ok ,I'll try to learn how to use it ,thank you!

Comment: Essentially you are labouring under the delusion that, for a continuous function $f$ that is differentiable on $(a,b)\setminus\{y\}$, $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(y+x)-f(y)}x$ exists if and only if $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(y+x)$ exists, in which case they are equal. What is true that, for a continuous function $f$ that is differentiable on $(a,b)\setminus\{y\}$, $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(y+x)-f(y)}x$ exists if $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(y+x)$ exists, in which case they are equal. The other implication doesn't hold.

Comment: i actually hold this 'delusion',however,i just wonder what do you mean by saying 'they are equal', i guess if they were equal,there won't be such a problem occuring in this picture.